# Como llamar a una función desde un trigger

Tags: oracle

Aun estoy explorando el mundo de Oracle y me encontré con una situación, espero que me ayuden :)

Tengo una Función ya construida esta solo se encarga de cargar unas consultas y me devuelve los respectivos valores, Mi tabla sensor es una tabla que se encuentra en producción por lo que los valores cargados a través de esta función siempre van a variar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_INDICADOR (
id_sensor in VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  MSG VARCHAR2(200);
  v_query_insert VARCHAR2 (500);
  err_code VARCHAR2(100);
  err_msg VARCHAR2(150);
BEGIN
 -- cargamos la consulta contenida en el indicador
    SELECT query INTO v_query_insert FROM SENSOR WHERE IDSENSOR=id_sensor;
    -- ejecutamos la consulta
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_insert INTO MSG;

RETURN MSG;

EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN
 -- se registra el codigo de error
          err_code := SQLCODE;
          -- se registra el mensaje de error
          err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
MSG:= SQLCODE ||'- '||err_msg; -- Error de aplicacion 
RETURN MSG;
END;
```

Ahora, solo tengo un trigger que actualiza el campo ACTUALIZACION con la fecha actual del sistema siempre y cuando haga cambios sobre mi tabla sensor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_VALOR
BEFORE UPDATE ON SENSOR REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
v_fecha DATE;
BEGIN
v_fecha :=SYSDATE;
SELECT SYSDATE INTO v_fecha FROM DUAL;
:NEW.ACTUALIZACION :=v_fecha;
END;
```

Mi consulta es como podría hacer el llamado de esta Función desde mi Trigger.
Gracias.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_VALOR
  BEFORE UPDATE ON SENSOR REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE 
    v_fecha DATE;
    v_indicador NUMBER;
  BEGIN
--ESTE PROCESO SOLO ME DA LA FECHA ACTUAL DEL SISTEMA Y LA REGISTRA EN 
--MICAMPO ACTUALIZACION
     v_fecha :=SYSDATE;
     SELECT SYSDATE INTO v_fecha FROM DUAL;
    :NEW.ACTUALIZACION :=v_fecha;
     --LLAMADA DE MI FUNCION
     v_indicador := FN_INDICADOR(IDSENSOR);
  END;
```

Comment: ok :) ahora mismo

Answer (score 1):

Para llamar cualquier funcion, desde un trigger (que no es mas que una funcion particular, que se ejecuta particularmente cuando la tabla sufre algun tipo de modificacion) o desde otra funcion, lo que hace falta es llamarla por el nombre de la base en la que esta + el nombre de la funcion.

Si tu funcion esta en la misma base, alcanza con hacer

```
FN_INDICADOR(parametro);
```

Si por ejemplo, esa función estuviera en otro esquema (por ejemplo esquema1), habria que hacer:

```
esquema1.FN_INDICADOR(parametro);
```

Recorda que si tiene un valor de retorno, el mismo se recibe en una variable de la siguiente forma:

```
v_regreso := FN_INDICADOR(parametro);
```

Y debes declarar esa variable, en este caso `v_regreso varchar;`

Comment: ok Doc. ya publique la pregunta espero haberme dejado entender. :D

Comment: Y ¿para llamar a una función desde un procedimiento (procedure)?

Comment: @MaríaMagdalenaBlancoRodas Si tenes una nueva pregunta, hacela... no dejes un comentario sobre una respuesta, y menos si tiene 3 años...